# How to solve Syntax error in Update query in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

> I am updating `Status_msg` column using `Update` query in Sqlite Database by value 1 to 0. The Syntax error occurred when compiling the application.
>
> The Log cat

```
 02-20 09:45:36.145 19350-19350/com.smsfilter E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "1": syntax error
    02-20 09:45:36.145 19350-19350/com.smsfilter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    02-20 09:45:36.145 19350-19350/com.smsfilter W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread   exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
   02-20 09:45:36.195 19350-19350/com.smsfilter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): ,  while compiling: UPDATE sms_tbl SET 1 = 0 where 1 = 1
                                                                   at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                   at         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnecti on.java:882)
                                                                   at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
                                                                   at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
                                                                   at com.smsfilter.DB_Message.setStatus(DB_Message.java:106)
                                                                   at com.smsfilter.SpamActivity$datalist$1.onCheckedChanged(SpamActivity.java:208)
                                                                   at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:126)
                                                                   at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
                                                                   at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> The Update function is given below

```
    public int setStatus(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String status_change_query = "UPDATE " + DB_Table1 + " SET " +  Status_Msg + " = 0 where " + Status_Msg + " = 1";
    Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(status_change_query,null);
    cursor.close();
    System.out.println(""+ Status_Msg);
    sqldb.close();
    return Status_Msg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String status_change_query = "UPDATE " + DB_Table1 + " SET " +  Status_Msg + " = 0 where " + Status_Msg + " = 1";
```

gives

```
UPDATE sms_tbl SET 1 = 0 where 1 = 1 at
```

In other words, you seem to have simply mixed up your variables.

`Status_Msg` should be your column name but it seems to instead be a numeric value, and the resulting query is invalid SQL.

Comment: I does not understand

Comment: @amarpatil Do you have a variable or constant that contains the _name_ of the column you're trying to update?

Comment: ` public static  final int Status_Msg = 1;` This is a constant

Comment: @amarpatil If that is meant to be a constant for the name of your column, it needs to say something like `public static final String Status_Msg = "Status_Msg";`.

Comment: @amarpatil The column name could be seen in the CREATE TABLE statement.